# Access WCF from many websites and applications with each EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have WCF which is used in many website and applications. All projects have same database with different data.

I want each projects call WCF to get data from its database

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to show more details

Comment: I made wcf for e-commerce. I will use it in many websites each website has its database.I need to pass connection string to wcf to work with EF